# Want to make my text on custom loader responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to make my centered div text responsive on my website loader. The clue is I don't know how I am be able to do this. Im a learning coder so I hope someone can help me with my problem :)

NOTE! Load the snippet in full page so you can see the text :P

Here is the source code:

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden
}

#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url(https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/200000/velka/plain-red-background.jpg);
    z-index: 99;
    /* makes sure it stays on top */
}

#camera {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
    top: 50%;
    /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/6kD.svg);
    /* path to your loading animation */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px/* is width and height divided by two */
}

#text {
    line-height: 890px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
        <div id="text">Website loading...</div>
        <div id="camera"></div>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to be using here is display: flex; as that allows you to center elements both horizontally and vertially. This is also known as a flexbox.

Some other notes regarding the code, you should have the image as an image rather than a background image in this case, and it is much easier to use background-color: red; than using an image as a background color.

```css
body,
  html {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  body {
   overflow: hidden
  }

  #preloader {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: red;
   z-index: 99;
   /* makes sure it stays on top */
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;

   display: flex;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;

   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
  }

  #camera {

   height: 150px;


   /* path to your loading animation */
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;

   background-size: contain;

   display: flex;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;

   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
  }

  #text {
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 890px;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;

   display: flex;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;

   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<body>

 <div id="preloader">
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/6kD.svg" id="camera">
  <div id="text">Website loading...</div>


 </div>

</body>
```

Cheers!

Should note:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
```

This just makes sure that the centring works on all browsers.

Comment: @StevenBergosso19 No problem! If there's anything I wrote that you're confused about feel free to ask! Best to know how it works :)

Comment: @StevenBergosso19 Absolutely! The benefit of using inline images, for a case like this, is the ability to size it easily and efficiently. If you assign the svg both a width and a height, it will be distorted unless you give the right aspect ratio. So only give it a height or width, and it will scale properly. Right now, under #camera, the height is 150px but you can change it to whatever you like, or use width. You should also look into alternative ways of measurement than pixels, I would suggest looking at this: https://www.beginnersguidetohtml.com/guides/css/sizes/pixels-ems-percentages

Answer (score 0):

I think using flexbox here would be better idea

I have added flexbox styles for `#preloader`

```
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/200000/velka/plain-red-background.jpg);
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* makes sure it stays on top */
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o693b2wj/) with other changes to make everything correct